# Decrypt / Verify Firebase token

Tags: java, android, firebase, jwt

I'm using Firebase with a Email & Password authentication. Once the user has been signed in successfully I'll receive an `AuthData` object which contains a token.
I wanna send this token to my backend, verify it and extract the `uid` from it - unfortunately I don't know how to do this.

I'm aware of the Firebase secret and if I go to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/), enter the token and the secret the signature is verified and I see the correct payload - so this actually works.
Since I'm running Java on my backend I've been using [jjwt](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) for the decryption process unfortunately it always throws a `SignatureException`:

> io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.

Following the code I've been using:

```
SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;
byte[] encodedKey = Base64.decode("my-firebase-secret", Base64.DEFAULT);
Key k = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, signatureAlgorithm.getJcaName());
Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(k)
                    .parseClaimsJws("the-token").getBody();
```

I've also tried it with the following snippet:

```
Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("my-firebase-secret"))
                    .parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();
```

But got the same exception. So what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When the user is signed in calling getAuth() will return an object with a uid field. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/getauth.html

Comment: @RonHarlev I'm aware of that unfortunately I don't want to send the UID in plain text to my server since this would render the security behind JWT useless. And even if I do so I still need to verify that the token is valid and not some generated stuff that an unauthorized 3rd party came up with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to use getBytes instead of parseBase64Binary? Here is the example:

```
Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("my-firebase-secret".getBytes("UTF-8")).parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much.